# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807) on iOS simulator with localhost

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to connect `openssl s_server` and iOS client using TCP SSL, but get `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)`.

**Objective-C code([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941559/2656632)):**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    printf("method started \n");

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSData *iosTrustedCertDerData =
    [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"servercert"
                                                    ofType:@"der"]];

    OSStatus            err = noErr;
    SecCertificateRef   cert;

    cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef) iosTrustedCertDerData);
    assert(cert != NULL);

    CFTypeRef result;

    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          (id)kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
                          cert, kSecValueRef,
                          nil];

    err = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)dict, &result);
    assert(err == noErr || err == errSecDuplicateItem);

    printf("adding finished \n");


    if ((err == noErr) ||
        (err == errSecDuplicateItem)) {

        printf("success \n");

        CFReadStreamRef readStream;
        CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL,
                                           (CFStringRef)@"localhost",
                                           1678,
                                           &readStream,
                                           &writeStream);
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream,
                                kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel,
                                kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1);
        CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
        CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);

        UInt8 buf[] = "Hello from iOS";
        int bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, buf, strlen((char*)buf));

    } else {
        printf("error!");
    }

    CFRelease(cert);
}
```

**Sequence of commands to create the certificate and start the server (please pay attention to the 11 step: on the server side I use pem certificate and on the client side I use der certificate), file samples I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/2656632):**

1.`touch openssl-ca.cnf`

2.Copy-pasted sample in openssl-ca.cnf. Only one line changed:

`commonName_default      = localhost`

3.`openssl req -x509 -config openssl-ca.cnf -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out cacert.pem -outform PEM`

4.`touch openssl-server.cnf`

5.Copy-pasted sample in openssl-server.cnf. Only two lines changed:

`commonName_default      = localhost`

`DNS.1       = localhost`

6.`openssl req -config openssl-server.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -out servercert.csr -outform PEM`

7.Added 2 +1 sections in openssl-ca.cnf:

```
[ CA_default ]
    ...
    base_dir    = .
    certificate = $base_dir/cacert.pem  # The CA certifcate
    private_key = $base_dir/cakey.pem   # The CA private key
    new_certs_dir   = $base_dir     # Location for new certs after signing
    database    = $base_dir/index.txt   # Database index file
    serial      = $base_dir/serial.txt  # The current serial number

    unique_subject  = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several certificates with same subject.
```

...

```
####################################################################
[ signing_policy ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ signing_req ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
```

8.`touch index.txt`

9.`echo '01' > serial.txt`

10.`openssl ca -config openssl-ca.cnf -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req -out servercert.pem -infiles servercert.csr`

11.`openssl x509 -in servercert.pem -inform PEM -out servercert.der -outform DER`

12.Added servercert.der in iOS project

13.`let sslsock = SSLSocketLite(inHost: "localhost", inPort: 1678)`

14.Exception Domains -> +`localhost`

15.`openssl s_server -key serverkey.pem -cert servercert.pem -accept 1678`

Final version of `openssl-ca.cnf`:

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

[ CA_default ]

default_days    = 1000          # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = sha256        # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

x509_extensions = ca_extensions     # The extensions to add to the cert

email_in_dn = no            # Don't concat the email in the DN
copy_extensions = copy          # Required to copy SANs from CSR to cert

base_dir    = .
certificate = $base_dir/cacert.pem  # The CA certifcate
private_key = $base_dir/cakey.pem   # The CA private key
new_certs_dir   = $base_dir     # Location for new certs after signing
database    = $base_dir/index.txt   # Database index file
serial      = $base_dir/serial.txt  # The current serial number

unique_subject  = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                # several certificates with same subject.
####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 4096
default_keyfile     = cakey.pem
distinguished_name  = ca_distinguished_name
x509_extensions     = ca_extensions
string_mask         = utf8only

####################################################################
[ ca_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Maryland

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Baltimore

organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Test CA, Limited

organizationalUnitName  = Organizational Unit (eg, division)
organizationalUnitName_default  = Server Research Department

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = localhost

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

####################################################################
[ ca_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always, issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign

####################################################################
[ signing_policy ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ signing_req ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
```

Final version of openssl-server.cnf:

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = serverkey.pem
distinguished_name  = server_distinguished_name
req_extensions      = server_req_extensions
string_mask         = utf8only

####################################################################
[ server_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = MD

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Baltimore

organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Test CA, Limited

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = localhost

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

####################################################################
[ server_req_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

####################################################################
[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = localhost
```

iOS output:

> method started
>   adding finished
>   success
>   2016-08-30 19:17:06.619
>   ssltest[5418:141544] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)

OpenSSL s_server output(nothing happened):

> Using default temp DH parameters
>
> ACCEPT

What have I missed? And how can I solve it?

Maybe someone can share working cert with the `localhost` address in the `commonName`? Using this I will understand which exactly is the problem: cert and my `pem` to `der` converting or iOS app.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... How does this question differ from [“CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)” with local IP in “Exception Domains”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39185678)?

Comment: @jww >"Please forgive my ignorance" - That's ok, I understand. >"How does this question differ from...?" - It differs in following: this time I use Objective-C tested code. Before I found on the github some Swift code which I had to modify. I was not sure of the correctness of it. Now I use "trusted", unmodified and holistic code sample from StackOverflow. Unfortunately that's all what I can do now. And I also notify you again that I use pem version of certificate for server and der version for client(from 11 step), is this ok?

Comment: @jww it's been three weeks but I still don't understand my mistake, all looks right, but just doesn't works... Maybe you could share working cert with the `localhost` address in the `commonName`? Using this I will understand which exactly is the problem: cert and my `pem` to `der` converting or iOS app.

Comment: 2 things I can think of are 1. Your host is not supporting a  valid version of TLS SSL, you could probably fix this by defining exception domains in your app's Info.plist file; 2. You are not connected to Internet and your host is depending in an external CA that needs Internet connection.

Comment: @BlackSheep that's funny, but a few hours ago I finally connected iPhone simulator to my OS X openssl server using [this tutorial](https://github.com/seviu/iOS-SSL-localhost). But now I need to find how can I do this programmatically(without `iosCertTrustManager.py` script)?

Comment: @don-prog Did you get any solution?

Comment: @SanyasiraoMopada sorry for the delay, yes, I used [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761837/ios-ssl-connection-in-swift).